# print(range(…)) statement output is “range(…)” instead of integer values

Tags: python

I was trying different ways of using the `range()` function in Python and when I tried this:

```
print(range(1, 20, 2), end=" ")
```

I got an output like this: `range(1, 20, 2 )` , when I was expecting something like this: `1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19`  Why is this the case?

Also, are there any other ways to print a range of numbers other than using a loop statement, or is it compulsory to always use loops if I want a sequence of numbers using `range()`?

Comment: `range` provides you an iterable object, not the actual list of integers

Answer (score 2):

`range(1, 20, 2)` return `object`, you need  iterate over this and print all element you can do this with `for-loop` or `print` do this for you but you need pass `list` to `print` and `print` iterate over all element in `list`.

You can use `*` then get all elements and print what you want:

```
>>> print(*range(1, 20, 2), end = " ")
1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 

# this same like below:

>>> list(range(1,20,2))
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]

>>> print(*[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19], sep= ' ')
1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19
```

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you explain *why* it's not doing what they want.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it worked but why are we using * here. What is the logic behind it? I want to know about that.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting the output `range(1, 20, 2)` is because you are trying to print an object of the class `range`, and as @user1740577 pointed out, you can use `print(*range(1, 20, 2), end = " ")` to print out the numbers as you intend to.